# How to Trigger Keyboard shortcut (ctrl+alt+R) using javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to create a webpage that should be able to record the screen automatically. I am using "Screencastify" chrome extension to record the screen. Here we need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to start/stop recording.
Is there any way to start/stop recording from a page's javascript?
Please let me know your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid not.

Even if Screencastify has some API exposed (e.g. a custom event you could raise), it would probably run into problems that recording screen requires an explicit invocation of the extension by the user.

That said, a quick glance shows that there is no such API exposed.